# Sort Macedonian alphabet using collation

Tags: java, collation

I'm trying to sort a set of strings written in Macedonian alphabet. I know how to do it, but the end result isn't what I expected. Here is my test program:

```
public class Main {

    private static final char[] ALPHABET_ARRAY = {
        'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ѓ', 'е', 'ж', 'з', 'ѕ', 'и', 'ј', 'к', 'л', 'љ', 'м', 'н', 'њ', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ќ', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч','џ', 'ш' };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("mk", "MK"));
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_ARRAY.length; i++) {
            list.add("" + ALPHABET_ARRAY[i]);
        }
        list.sort(collator::compare);
        list.forEach(System.out::print);
    }
}
```

The letters in `ALPHABET_ARRAY` are in the correct alphabetical order, but the program prints

> абвгѓдежзѕијкќлљмнњопрстуфхцчџш

But it should have been:

> абвгдѓежзѕијклљмнњопрстќуфхцчџш

Is there a problem with the Macedonian collator in Java or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like Java doesn't differ between "г" and "ѓ" // "к" and "ќ", but that's strange.

Comment: The letters ѓ and ќ are where the Macedonian alphabet differs from other Cyrillic alphabets like Croatian and Serbian. This also explains why their unicode values are outside of the rest of the codes for the letters in the Macedonian alphabet.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macedonian_alphabet#Unique_letters

Comment: Judging by the mk_MK `collator.getRules()` it places 'ѓ' before 'д', therefore the problem is with Macedonian collator in Java. The Javadoc for `RuleBasedCollator` explains how to create your own collator with your own rules if you really need it.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin thanks! If you put that in an answer I'll make sure to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collator for "mk_MK" locale is based on the `sun.text.resources.mk.CollationData_mk` resource ([CollationData_mk.java source in jdk8u repo tagged jdk8u92-b14](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/4f06a20cdc59/src/share/classes/sun/text/resources/mk/CollationData_mk.java)).

The collator rules in `CollationData_mk` clearly place 'ѓ' right after 'г' and 'ќ' right after 'к'.

As it is possible to create `RuleBasedCollator` with custom rules, the simplest way to get the sorting order that you need is to modify the rules from `CollationData_mk` a little:

```
public static Collator createMacedonianCollator() throws ParseException {
    // the defaults are defined in non-public sun.util.locale.provider.CollationRules
    // they are used internally in sun.util.locale.provider.CollatorProviderImpl
    // we have no direct access to proper defaults, so we will simply comment entries which depend on them
    String DEFAULTRULES = "";
    // we will move the entries for ѓ and ќ only, leaving everything else as is
    return new RuleBasedCollator( DEFAULTRULES +
            //"& 9 < \u0482 " +       // thousand sign
            //"& Z " +                // Arabic script sorts after Z's
            "< \u0430 , \u0410" +   // a
            "< \u0431 , \u0411" +   // be
            "< \u0432 , \u0412" +   // ve
            "< \u0433 , \u0413" +   // ghe
            "; \u0491 , \u0490" +   // ghe-upturn
            "; \u0495 , \u0494" +   // ghe-mid-hook
            /*!!!moved after д/de!!!*/ //"; \u0453 , \u0403" +   // gje
            "; \u0493 , \u0492" +   // ghe-stroke
            "< \u0434 , \u0414" +   // de
            /*!!!moved AND relation strength changed!!!*/ "< \u0453 , \u0403" +   // gje
            "< \u0452 , \u0402" +   // dje
            "< \u0435 , \u0415" +   // ie
            "; \u04bd , \u04bc" +   // che
            "; \u0451 , \u0401" +   // io
            "; \u04bf , \u04be" +   // che-descender
            "< \u0454 , \u0404" +   // uk ie
            "< \u0436 , \u0416" +   // zhe
            "; \u0497 , \u0496" +   // zhe-descender
            "; \u04c2 , \u04c1" +   // zhe-breve
            "< \u0437 , \u0417" +   // ze
            "; \u0499 , \u0498" +   // zh-descender
            "< \u0455 , \u0405" +   // dze
            "< \u0438 , \u0418" +   // i
            "< \u0456 , \u0406" +   // uk/bg i
            "; \u04c0 " +           // palochka
            "< \u0457 , \u0407" +   // uk yi
            "< \u0439 , \u0419" +   // short i
            "< \u0458 , \u0408" +   // je
            "< \u043a , \u041a" +   // ka
            "; \u049f , \u049e" +   // ka-stroke
            "; \u04c4 , \u04c3" +   // ka-hook
            "; \u049d , \u049c" +   // ka-vt-stroke
            "; \u04a1 , \u04a0" +   // bashkir-ka
            /*!!!moved after т/te!!!*/ //"; \u045c , \u040c" +   // kje
            "; \u049b , \u049a" +   // ka-descender
            "< \u043b , \u041b" +   // el
            "< \u0459 , \u0409" +   // lje
            "< \u043c , \u041c" +   // em
            "< \u043d , \u041d" +   // en
            "; \u0463 " +           // yat
            "; \u04a3 , \u04a2" +   // en-descender
            "; \u04a5 , \u04a4" +   // en-ghe
            "; \u04bb , \u04ba" +   // shha
            "; \u04c8 , \u04c7" +   // en-hook
            "< \u045a , \u040a" +   // nje
            "< \u043e , \u041e" +   // o
            "; \u04a9 , \u04a8" +   // ha
            "< \u043f , \u041f" +   // pe
            "; \u04a7 , \u04a6" +   // pe-mid-hook
            "< \u0440 , \u0420" +   // er
            "< \u0441 , \u0421" +   // es
            "; \u04ab , \u04aa" +   // es-descender
            "< \u0442 , \u0422" +   // te
            "; \u04ad , \u04ac" +   // te-descender
            "< \u045b , \u040b" +   // tshe
            /*!!!movedAND relation strength changed!!!*/ "< \u045c , \u040c" +   // kje
            "< \u0443 , \u0423" +   // u
            "; \u04af , \u04ae" +   // straight u
            "< \u045e , \u040e" +   // short u
            "< \u04b1 , \u04b0" +   // straight u-stroke
            "< \u0444 , \u0424" +   // ef
            "< \u0445 , \u0425" +   // ha
            "; \u04b3 , \u04b2" +   // ha-descender
            "< \u0446 , \u0426" +   // tse
            "; \u04b5 , \u04b4" +   // te tse
            "< \u0447 , \u0427" +   // che
            "; \u04b7 ; \u04b6" +   // che-descender
            "; \u04b9 , \u04b8" +   // che-vt-stroke
            "; \u04cc , \u04cb" +   // che
            "< \u045f , \u040f" +   // dzhe
            "< \u0448 , \u0428" +   // sha
            "< \u0449 , \u0429" +   // shcha
            "< \u044a , \u042a" +   // hard sign
            "< \u044b , \u042b" +   // yeru
            "< \u044c , \u042c" +   // soft sign
            "< \u044d , \u042d" +   // e
            "< \u044e , \u042e" +   // yu
            "< \u044f , \u042f" +   // ya
            "< \u0461 , \u0460" +   // omega
            "< \u0462 " +           // yat
            "< \u0465 , \u0464" +   // iotified e
            "< \u0467 , \u0466" +   // little yus
            "< \u0469 , \u0468" +   // iotified little yus
            "< \u046b , \u046a" +   // big yus
            "< \u046d , \u046c" +   // iotified big yus
            "< \u046f , \u046e" +   // ksi
            "< \u0471 , \u0470" +   // psi
            "< \u0473 , \u0472" +   // fita
            "< \u0475 , \u0474" +   // izhitsa
            "; \u0477 , \u0476" +   // izhitsa-double-grave
            "< \u0479 , \u0478" +   // uk
            "< \u047b , \u047a" +   // round omega
            "< \u047d , \u047c" +   // omega-titlo
            "< \u047f , \u047e" +   // ot
            "< \u0481 , \u0480"     // koppa
    );
}
```

The rules can be simplified further to contain only the base 31 letters without accented variants.

Comment: And ideally somebody should create an issue in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net describing the problem with `CollationData_mk` and citing some proper references about the proper collation rules for Macedonian locale.

Comment: Thank you so much! And as a matter of fact, I already filed a bug on http://bugs.java.com. If it gets approved I will add a link to my question for posterity.